# Finding who donated what troops and when

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, it is quite regular to see wrong troops donated to my request. Is there any way to find out "who" donated "which" troops to "anyone" in my Clan.

Currently, we can only see the name of the person who donated the troops at the time of donation in the game.

Also, I found a [Discord bot](https://discordbots.org/bot/427301910291415051) which helps to know "who donated to whom and when". By the help of this data, and seeing the troops in my Clan Castle, I can deduce "who donated me which troops". Also, this method would mostly only work for my account, but I can't track "who donated which troops" to others in **my** clan.

I would like to know about the methods, tools or websites to this specific type of donation tracking.